# can't install react-native-cloudinary-image-display

Tags: react-native

npm install react-native-cloudinary-image-display

is failing ,I am getting the below ,please help

31717 warn react-native-paper@4.9.1 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
31718 warn react-native-paper@4.9.1 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
31719 warn react-native-safe-area-context@3.2.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
31720 warn react-native-iphone-x-helper@1.3.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.42.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
31721 verbose stack Error: npm-insights@1.0.9 postinstall: `npm-insights:init`
31721 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
31721 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
31721 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
31721 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
31721 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
31722 verbose pkgid npm-insights@1.0.9
31723 verbose cwd /Users//Desktop/react-native-with-firebase-course/my-test-project
31724 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
31725 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "react-native-cloudinary-image-display"
31726 verbose node v14.15.1
31727 verbose npm  v6.14.8
31728 error code ELIFECYCLE
31729 error syscall spawn
31730 error file sh
31731 error errno ENOENT
31732 error npm-insights@1.0.9 postinstall: `npm-insights:init`
31732 error spawn ENOENT
31733 error Failed at the npm-insights@1.0.9 postinstall script.
31733 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
31734 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
npm i --save react-native-cloudinary-image-display
```

Or importing core modules?

```
npm install lodash
npm install cloudinary-core
```

Or this:

```
npm install --save-dev xxxxx
```

Finally try this:

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers

npm-install-peers
```

I don't know what you have already tried, please edit your question for better results

Comment: Thanks,I have tried all those,this is the error I see in logs,sh: npm-insights:init: command not found, npm ERR! npm-insights@1.0.9 postinstall: `npm-insights:init`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!

Comment: Maybe this post will help resolve that particular issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942118/npm-err-error-spawn-enoent

Comment: thanks will check it ,by the way can anyone guide me about any alternative on how to read data from cloudinary repo apart from using this package .cloudinary-react seems not working on react native

Comment: I cannot help you with that, another post. BTW, if you found this answer useful please mark it as accepted, that will help other people with the similar problem know that this worked

Comment: thanks ,but that didn't fix my issue,I still cannot install the package